# Permission denied on network/samba share while accessing HG repo

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, mercurial, samba, network-share

I am using EclipsePHP in Ubuntu 10.10 and try to use Mercurial (HG) to work with a repository that's located on my network-connected staging server (samba share).

When trying to refresh the repository from within Eclipse (`hg status` really) , I get the following error thrown in my face: `abort: Operation not permitted: /media/sharename/myrepository/.hg/.dirstate*` .

Whilst trying to find out what's wrong, I went to the network share from terminal and wrote `hg status` - the same error occurs, so it's not only occuring from within Eclipse. I tested to CHMOD the files from both my computer as well as the server - `chmod 777 /media/sharename/myrepository/ -R` - nothing changes.

But when I accidentally ran `sudo hg status` from the repo directory, Mercurial started the fireworks and worked like a charm.

What on earth is going wrong with my computer? Why can't i run my `hg` commands without being root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chmod will not help you here I guess. The ownership and permissions on the server side are not replicated to the client (no unix extensions on server) or your UID/GID differ between both machines. You can override file ownership when mounting via:

```
mount -t cifs //SERVER/SHARE /MOUNTPOINT -o uid=USERNAME
```

This is from memory though, check man mount.cifs for details. Also, alternative networked filesystems like NFS might serve you better in this case, or try sshfs.

Comment: Thanks a lot kread. Here's the actual line I've used in  `/etc/fstab` which may come handy if anyone gets the same issues as i had: `//192.168.1.1/development/repo /media/repo cifs exec,user=myUserName,pass=myPassword,umask=007,gid=46,uid=1000,quiet,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777 0 1`

Comment: mount.cifs version 6.4 doesn't support quiet, umask, or exec. Oh, and the options are now username=FOO and password=FOO

Answer (score 4):

You can mount your network drive like this. Open your /etc/fstab/, and then enter the following line.

> //IP_OR_HOSTNAME/DIRECTORY_NAME /MOUNT_DIRECTORY cifs user=sambauser,pass=sambapassword,auto,exec,umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

Hope it works.

Comment: Nice, I tried some of the above but no luck, then tried your snippet. Worked perfectly, thanks!